# Angular - Simple custom service not returning data back to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

Been scratching my head for weeks on this particular part of my code. What I have is a simple custom service that would fetch my data via ajax, I then perform a post process and lastly I want to return that data back to my controller. Even tough my service is creating my object correctly nothing ever gets back to my controller.

Ive tried using a "deferred.promise" method, which does seems to return data back to the controller but in a $$state object that I cannot access via the controller for some strange reason. This is a whole other issue.

I just need a simpleway to return data to my controller but all of the post process must be handled in my service. Would anyone know if this is possible?

Here is what i got.

My service:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);    

app.factory('MyService', function($http, $q, $timeout){

    var My_Stored_Data = {}

    return {

        load_my_data_service: function(){

            $http({
                method: 'GET',  
                url: 'AJAX PATH',
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8"} 
            }).then(function(data){

                //post-process my data before returning it to the controller $scope.return_my_data_here
                My_Stored_Data = data;
                My_Stored_Data.data_result_1 = My_Stored_Data.data_result_1.split("\r\n");
                My_Stored_Data.data_result_2 = My_Stored_Data.data_result_2.split("\r\n");
                console.log(My_Stored_Data)//logs shows the that "My_Stored_Data" has processed my data correctly.
                return My_Stored_Data //Return my data tot he controller $scope.return_my_data_here.

            });     

        }

    }               
});
```

My controller:

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope,$q,MyService) {

    $scope.fetch_my_data = function(){

        $scope.return_my_data_here = MyService.load_my_data_service();

    }
    $scope.fetch_my_data() //Initiate on page load

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ali Baig is correct.  You need the return as he has pointed out.  But the object returned is a promise and not the raw data as you are expecting so you also need this:

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope,$q,MyService) {

    $scope.fetch_my_data = function(){

        // MyService.load_my_data_service() will return a promise. 
        $scope.return_my_data_here = MyService.load_my_data_service();

        // Use .then() to do something with that promise.
        // NOTE: This code will run asynchronously.
        $scope.return_my_data_here.then(function(data){ 
            $scope.actualData = data;
            console.log($scope.actualData);
        });
    }
    $scope.fetch_my_data() //Initiate on page load
});
```

Comment: I would have added this to the comments on Ali Baig's answer but I do not have enough rep.

Comment: I was away, just saw it! You are spot on!

Comment: Wow that actually worked! been on this for weeks now. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AliBaig, can I attribute this to you or add you to this answer?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are missing a return statement just before `$http({..`

```
return {

    load_my_data_service: function(){

        return $http({
            method: 'GET',  
            url: 'AJAX PATH',
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8"} 
        }).then(function(result){    
            return result.data;    //to make it cleaner, just return the promise itself to your controller..
        });    

    }

}
```

This will resolve your service problems. And then in your controller, use

```
$scope.return_my_data_here = {};

MyService.load_my_data_service().then(function(data){
    var My_Stored_Data = data;
    My_Stored_Data.data_result_1 = My_Stored_Data.data_result_1.split("\r\n");
    My_Stored_Data.data_result_2 = My_Stored_Data.data_result_2.split("\r\n");
    $scope.return_my_data_here = My_Stored_Data;
});
```

Comment: Same thing, my $scope is still empty. Any other ideas?

Comment: @DanielEllison Give it a try now, I have added my changes.